# Building sql insert strings on the fly in Ruby on Rails to improve performance

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use the following code to get a sql insert string to build an insert statement for bulk insertion of large numbers of records. I need this because saving them singly via ActiveRecord is slow.

Adding them in via activerecord-import is also too slow -- much slower than my current method. E.g., my method takes 15 seconds where activerecord-import takes 4 minutes 10 seconds on a sample bulk insert of 100k records (which is typical for me).

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_sql_insert_string
  "('#{entry_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}',
    #{field1.nil? ? "NULL" : field1},
    #{field2.nil? ? "NULL" : field2},
    #{field3.nil? ? "NULL" : field3})"
  end
end
```

The problem is that this is fragile. Every time I add a field, I need to remember to include it in this method. Can I use dynamic programming (define_method) to build this once when the class loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few tools that exist that will make your life a lot easier.  Rather than write your own sql insert statements I would recommend using a gem such as [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki) which will handle doing the bulk inserts for you.

To squeeze the last bit of performance out of activerecord-import you can use the columns property of your active record classes.  For instance

```
columns = MyClass.columns.map(&:name)
values = my_instances.map { |x| MyClass.columns.map { |y| x.send(y.name) } }
MyClass.import columns, values, :validate => false
```

Comment: Activerecord-import is far too slow.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, make sure when using activerecord-import that the :validate option is set to false.

Comment: Good suggestion. That shaved down most of the time. Now it takes 25 seconds for the same insert that takes my method 15 seconds. Not bad, but I still want to look into define_method or somesuch to get the robustness without slowing down.

Comment: You can use [instance.attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes) or Model.columns to help you out.  I added an example to my answer.  If you don't want to use a helper gem you can just use those in your string builder.

Comment: Another improvement -- That gets us down to 20 seconds.